# Unable to get telegram inline buttons to work

Tags: node.js, telegram, botframework

I was working with MS Bot framework and wanted to display some inline buttons on telegram after going through the documentation and some related questions i wrote the following but after session.send(temp) I'm not getting any buttons on the channel.

```
var temp = {
"type": "Message",
"from": { "channelID":"telegram", "address": session.message.from.id},
"to": { "channelID":"telegram", "address": session.message.to.id},
"conversationId": session.message.conversationId,
"channelData": {
    "method": "editMessageReplyMarkup",
    "parameters": {
        "message_id": session.message.id,
            "reply_markup": {
                "inline_keyboard": [
                    [{"text": "Show me more options", "callback_data": "next"}],
                    [{"text": "Start a new search", "callback_data": "quit"}]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
session.send(temp);
```

Comment: Please explain "it does not seem to work".

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are supported natively in BotFramework so you don't need to use ChannelData. ([See Docs](http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html))

```
"buttons": 
[
    {
        "type": "imBack",
        "title": "Show me more options",
        "value": "next"
    },
    {
        "type": "imBack",
        "title": "Start a new search",
        "value": "quit"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to achieve this through channelData, you must stringify the value of the reply_markup field, e.g.:

```
"reply_markup": JSON.stringify({
            "inline_keyboard": [
                [{"text": "Show me more options", "callback_data": "next"}],
                [{"text": "Start a new search", "callback_data": "quit"}]
            ]
        })
```